# How to perform Firebase storage image upload in a multi field Form to getDownloadURL and set to State for Redux usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux

The whole dispatch(addproductStart.....) section yields red lines with Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.eslintno-unused-expressions

I'm wondering what's wrong with the function.
It is essentially a handleSubmit function that takes the Forminput of an Image set to productThumbnail State, then gets put into Firebase.Storage(), then getDownloadURL() gets put into a new State to be used within the Dispatched Redux function.

It must be a syntax thing.

Thanks!

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
 e.preventDefault();
        
        const storageRef= storage.ref(productThumbnail.name);
            storageRef.put(productThumbnail).then(() => {
                const postproductThumbnail = storageRef.getDownloadURL();
               
                setPostProductThumbnail(postproductThumbnail);   
            },
        )  
        dispatch(
            addProductStart({
                productCategory,
                productName,
                postproductThumbnail,
                productPrice,
                productDesc,
            })
        ),
        resetForm()
        }   
 return (
<h1> Manage Products</h1>

<FormInput
  className="field"
    label="Name"
 type="text"
   value={productName}
 handleChange={(e) =>
  setProductName(
  e.target.value
  )
   }
 />

 <FormInput
      className="field"
      label="Upload Product Image File"
      type="file"
      value={productThumbnail}
      handleChange={(e) => 
      setProductThumbnail(
      e.target.value                                                          
             )
        }     
   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `storageRef.put` and `storageRef.getDownloadURL` are asynchronous operations. This means that your `addProductStart` call that uses `postproductThumbnail` is called before `postproductThumbnail = storageRef.getDownloadURL()` ever runs. You can most easily check this by adding some `console.log` statements, or setting breakpoints on these lines and running in a debugger.

*On top of this problem your `const postproductThumbnail` won't be visible in the call to `addProductStart` because of where you declared it, but the main issue is the asynchronous nature of the calls.*

To fix this:

- Wait for the asynchronous result of `storageRef.getDownloadURL` with another `then()`.
- Move the call to `dispatch(addProductStart(...))` *into* the callback.

So something like:

```
const storageRef= storage.ref(productThumbnail.name);

storageRef.put(productThumbnail).then(() => {
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((postproductThumbnail) => {       
        setPostProductThumbnail(postproductThumbnail);
        dispatch(
            addProductStart({
                productCategory,
                productName,
                postproductThumbnail,
                productPrice,
                productDesc,
            })
        )
})
```

Comment: Hi Frank, very happy to learn from you, I see you around here a lot.

Comment: I have another error immediately however, I'm not handling Storage correctly. Should I make another post? I get "The operation 'put' cannot be performed on a root reference, ...."

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to manually make a folder called productThumbnail, or refer to a new Storage folder correctly.

Comment: Always search for an error message you get please, as I'm pretty sure this one has been covered before. You can't write directly to the root of your storage bucket, but you need to have at least a file name. Since you do `const storageRef= storage.ref(productThumbnail.name)`, could it be that `productThumbnail.name` is empty?

Comment: Yes thank you I understand order needs to be kept here, I have referred to SO post:56808608 however for some reason it does not have very many views despite being a top result, and now I'm on youtube as well. Yes productThumbnail refers to the image I just uploaded. We just need all the uploaded images in 1 folder in order to get the getDownloadURL.

Comment: I'm going over the docs as well and may check out one of the Firebase discords/slacks as well.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any way to separate the dispatch function and the getDownloadURL action so that getDownloadURL completes and then I can call it into  a separate dispatch component

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why would you want to separate them, when you need the download URL in the dispatch result? Or is it something like I helped with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856460/how-to-append-an-arrays-data-to-a-dom-element-in-order-of-retrieval-insertion-f/68856642#68856642)?

Comment: Hi Frank, it would just make it easier on me to solve the asynchronous stuff and the flow of this function if I could just separate the dispatching from the handleSubmit function.