# How to append an array's data to a DOM element in order of retrieval/insertion from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Google Firebase Firestore to store data and the Open Movie Database (OMD) with Axios to get movie information.

I'm making a website where you can add movies to collections. Inside the collections page, it currently shows all the movies you've added to any collection. These collections are stored in the user's Firestore doc.

Here is what a particular user's entire movies collections object looks like:

```
movies_collections = {
    "New": {
        "description": "",
        "movies": [
            "tt0092007_2021-08-19T21:00:45.072Z",
            "tt0042192_2021-08-19T21:01:06.280Z",
            "tt0160862_2021-08-19T21:01:09.345Z",
            "tt0164184_2021-08-19T21:01:12.662Z",
            "tt5294550_2021-08-19T21:01:17.820Z"
        ],
        "dateCreated": {
            "seconds": 1629406839,
            "nanoseconds": 22000000
        },
        "createdBy": "foo@gmail.com"
    },

    "Summer Watchlist": {
        "description": "to watch this summer",
        "movies": [
            "tt6964748_2021-08-20T02:37:21.933Z",
            "tt0043274_2021-08-20T02:37:29.024Z"
        ],
        "dateCreated": {
            "seconds": 1629427029,
            "nanoseconds": 718000000
        },
        "createdBy": "foo@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Here is the code which retrieves these movies, and then appends them to the DOM:

```
const userDocRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

// Get the movie collections
userDocRef.get().then((doc) => {

        // movies_collections ref
        const movies_collections = doc.data().movies_collections;

        // For each movies_collections key
        Object.keys(movies_collections).forEach(movies_collection_object => {

            // Get movies_collections -> {collection_name} -> movies array
            const movies_collections_movies_array = movies_collections[movies_collection_object].movies;

            // For each imdbID inside movies_collections -> {collection_name} -> movies array
            movies_collections_movies_array.forEach(movie => {

                // Get the imdbID
                let movie_imdbID = movie.split("_")[0];

                // Get movie's details
                axios.get("https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + movie_imdbID + "&apikey=56bdb7b4").then((res) => {
                    // Append the poster, title, and year to the DOM
                    document.getElementById("movies-collections-container").innerHTML +=
                        `
                    <div class="movie-container">
                        <div class="movie-image">
                            <img src=${res.data.Poster} alt="${res.data.Title} Poster">
                        </div>

                        <div class="movie-content">
                            <div class="add-content-container">
                                <div>
                                    <h2 class="movie-name">${res.data.Title}</h2>
                                    <p class="movie-release-date">Released: ${res.data.Year}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

The problem is, when it gets each movie's imdbID, it seems to get them in order, but when appending to the DOM, it seems to do it randomly. For example, if I refresh the collections page, it'll be a different order each time.

**How can I get my code to append each movie to the DOM according to their order in the "movies" array? I've added the timestamp each movie was inserted into the array as well if that can be used.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `axios.get("https://www.omdbapi.com/` calls all happen in parallel, and there's no guarantee they will complete in the order in which you start them.

You can either fire them sequentially (one by one), or you can add the element to the HTML before firing the `get` call, and then **update** the element when you get a response.

Something like this:

```jsx
function addMovieElementToContainerForID(movie_imdbID) {
    document.getElementById("movies-collections-container").innerHTML +=
      `<div class="movie-container" id="movie_${movie_imdbID}"></div>`;
}
function updateMovieElement(movie_imdbID, res) {
  let elm = document.getElementById(`movie_${movie_imdbID}`);
  elm.innerHTML = `
    <div class="movie-image">
        <img src=${res.data.Poster} alt="${res.data.Title} Poster">
    </div>

    <div class="movie-content">
        <div class="add-content-container">
            <div>
                <h2 class="movie-name">${res.data.Title}</h2>
                <p class="movie-release-date">Released: ${res.data.Year}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  `;
}

Object.keys(movies_collections).forEach(movies_collection_object => {
    const movies_collections_movies_array = movies_collections[movies_collection_object].movies;

    movies_collections_movies_array.forEach(movie => {
        let movie_imdbID = movie.split("_")[0];

        addMovieElementToContainerForID(movie_imdbID);

        axios.get("https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + movie_imdbID + "&apikey=56bdb7b4").then((res) => {
             updateMovieElement(movie_imdbID, res)
        })
    })
})
```